# Yet another issue with the RTL8821ce wifi card from Realtek

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek, dkms

I have encountered numerous issues with the rtl8821ce WiFi card on almost all Linux distros I have tried (including ChromeOS Flex), except for Arch Linux and EndeavourOS. Here is a snippet from `sudo dmesg`

```
[   14.581318] wlo1: authenticate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (local address=4c:eb:bd:0b:d0:1b)
[   14.713127] wlo1: send auth to 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[   14.749242] wlo1: authenticated
[   14.750050] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[   14.788915] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[   14.789470] wlo1: associated
[   18.299217] systemd-journald[299]: /var/log/journal/e9663d1213734ff7b14ddbd7c36e7379/user-1000.journal: Monotonic clock jumped backwards relative to last journal entry, rotating.
[   18.634410] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   21.066476] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   21.633816] kauditd_printk_skb: 21 callbacks suppressed
[   21.633818] audit: type=1400 audit(1711602848.847:143): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21184/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3657 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   21.633830] audit: type=1400 audit(1711602848.847:144): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/21184/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3657 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[   24.570189] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   24.680233] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   25.122087] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   25.232203] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   25.674463] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   25.784186] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   26.218202] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   26.328196] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   26.763073] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   26.873101] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   27.307121] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   27.418109] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   27.850346] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   27.960199] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   28.394192] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   28.504461] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   28.938461] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   29.048285] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   29.482193] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   29.592194] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   30.714436] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   30.824176] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   32.314464] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   32.795102] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   32.905159] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[   38.376686] warning: `ThreadPoolForeg' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[  513.540907] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[  513.650869] rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
[  518.395958] wlo1: authenticate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (local address=4c:eb:bd:0b:d0:1b)
[  518.527822] wlo1: send auth to 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  518.565151] wlo1: authenticated
[  518.565650] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  518.675742] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 2/3)
[  518.779646] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 3/3)
[  518.884705] wlo1: association with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f timed out
[  524.012679] wlo1: authenticate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (local address=4c:eb:bd:0b:d0:1b)
[  524.146568] wlo1: send auth to 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  524.184478] wlo1: authenticated
[  524.185371] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  524.230109] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[  524.230605] wlo1: associated
[  647.248980] wlo1: authenticate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (local address=4c:eb:bd:0b:d0:1b)
[  647.380823] wlo1: send auth to 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  647.417364] wlo1: authenticated
[  647.417641] wlo1: associate with 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (try 1/3)
[  647.456767] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 88:c3:97:39:db:2f (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=2)
[  647.457192] wlo1: associated
```

A snippet of `lspci -nnk` relating to the WiFi card:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, 8821ce
```

And here is the problem I had before setting `pcie_aspm=off` and `pci=noaer` in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub`

```
what is happening here?

[  350.349831] pcieport 0000:00:1d.1: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:02:00.0
[  350.349848] rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  350.349850] rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0:   device [10ec:c821] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
[  350.349851] rtl8821ce 0000:02:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
```

What do I do? I really don't wanna switch to Arch Linux again (for obvious reasons) so can anybody suggest a fix? I am on Ubuntu 23.10 at the moment and the rtl8821ce-dkms package is unavailable and i have installed the rtl8821ce-dkms driver from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce but I'm still encountering errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We feel really honored that you see us at StackExchange as the gods of kernel hackers. But I assume you better directly try to find a solution with the developer of the kernel driver.